# hibernate makes insert without reason

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Hello I'm new to JAVA hibernate and spring and I have a problem, I would apreciate so much if you could help me.
I will explain you.

- I have a application that has a inbox where all messages from the
  current user are listed.
- Then I have a form to insert new messages in the database, which it
  does all right.
- After you send that form and you create a new message, the controller
  returns you to the index page where all messages are listed again. 
  But when you refresh the page hibernate makes another insert into the
  database, without sending another "new message" form, just makes
  another insert when I refresh the index page...

I think that maybe it's because hibernate doesnt close the connection to the database propeperly, I dont know..
I will show you the functions that I use below:

I use the function **"enviarMensaje()"** in the delegate, wich it calls to the functions:

**enviarMensaje()** (to save a message object into the database) 

and **guardarMensajesDestinatario()** (to save 
several receivers objects into the database)

this is because a message has many receivers, so I have two tables for that.

here is the code:

DELEGATE FUNCTION

```
public String enviarMensaje(String[] mensajesDestinatariosStr, MenMensajes mensaje) {

    boolean respuesta=false;
    String strRespuesta = "error al enviar el mensaje";
    ArrayList<MenMensajesDestinatarios> destinatariosList=null;
    //MenMensajesDestinatarios md=null;
    try{
        respuesta=mensajesDAO.enviarMensaje(mensaje);

        for(String destinatarioStr : mensajesDestinatariosStr){
            MenMensajesDestinatarios md=new MenMensajesDestinatarios();
            System.out.println(destinatarioStr);
            BigDecimal usuarioIdNumber=new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(destinatarioStr));
            md.setUsuarioId(usuarioIdNumber);
            md.setFechaCreacion(mensaje.getFechaCreacion());
            md.setModificadoPor(mensaje.getModificadoPor());
            md.setCreadoPor(usuarioIdNumber);
            md.setMenMensajes(mensaje);
            md.setEstado(mensaje.getEstado());
            mensajesDAO.guardarMensajesDestinatario(md);

        }


        if (respuesta) {
            strRespuesta = "El mensaje ha sido eviado con exito";
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }


    return strRespuesta;
}
```

DAO FUNCTIONS

```
 public boolean enviarMensaje(MenMensajes mensaje){
    Session session = null;
    boolean exito=false;
    Transaction trx=null;
    try{
        session = sessionFactoryHestia.openSession();
        trx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(mensaje);
        trx.commit();
        session.flush();
        exito=true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error guardando datos");
        e.printStackTrace();
        trx.rollback();
        session.close();
    }
    return exito;
}


public void guardarMensajesDestinatario(MenMensajesDestinatarios md) {
    Session session=null;
    Transaction trx=null;
    try{
        session = sessionFactoryHestia.openSession();
        trx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(md);
        trx.commit();
        session.flush();

    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         e.getMessage();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

AND JUST IN CASE THE CONTROLLER

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "enviarMensaje.htm")
public String enviarMensaje(HttpSession session, @Valid @ModelAttribute("menMensaje") MenMensajes mensaje,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Integer intOpcion = 1;
    AppUsuarios user = (AppUsuarios) session.getAttribute("usuarioVO");//usuario de la sesion
    BigDecimal usuarioId = user.getUsuarioId();//guardar el id del usuario de la sesion para pasarlo como parametro
    String[] mensajesDestinatarios = request.getParameterValues("destinatarios");

    try {

       String respuesta = mensajesDelegate.enviarMensaje(mensajesDestinatarios, mensaje);

        modelMap.addAttribute("mensajes", mensajesDelegate.listarMensajesTodos(usuarioId, intOpcion));
        modelMap.addAttribute("opcion", intOpcion);
        modelMap.addAttribute("menMensaje", mensajesDelegate.cargarMensaje(usuarioId, null)); //pasarle un objeto MenMensajes al formulario de nuevo mensaje que esta oculto en un modal.
        modelMap.addAttribute("cboUsuarios", mensajesDelegate.cargarUsuarios()); //pasarle la lista de usuarios de la BD para combo de nuevo mensaje
        modelMap.addAttribute("cboTiposMensaje", mensajesDelegate.cargarTiposMensaje()); //pasarle la lista de tipos de mensaje de la BD para el combo de nuevo mensaje
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error en nuevoMensaje.htm");
    }
    return "/mensajes/index";
}
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with " But when you refresh the page ... " ? If you hit the browser refresh button?

Comment: **when you refresh the page** what is the stack of functions being called on refreshing the page..??

Comment: I think that when you are refreshing the page after insertion you are actually submitting the form again  it has nothing to do with hibernate

Comment: Yes I am with @RafikBELDI on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When refreshing the page you are actually submitting the form again that's why you are inserting multiple times, change the return of your save method to :

```
return "redirect:"+url;
```

Instead of :

```
return "/mensajes/index";
```

where `url` is a mapped url in your controller.